# Typo3 custom content element with content colPos

Tags: typo3, element

as I'm turning back to the real core functions of typo3 (which I used last before templatevoila), I wonder how I can create an content Element which acts like a container, where I can place content inside with the wizard.

As I got really enough from the flux-fluid update chaos, I think best solution ist to bet on the core functions.

I know, I can do this also with ext B13 container, but if it's possible somehow, I won't use any extensions as I can do it hopefully with core functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no container functionality inside TYPO3 core itself. I suggest using the b13 container extension which is well maintained and doesn't add much overhead.

Comment: Ok thanx for your expertise . As you are an old typo3-compagnion, I think, this is the most comfortable way. 

I know B13 well, so its ok using it. Hopefully, they don't make some harakiri like flux and fluid did (even with the typo-internal documentation which is gone very bad since the old core team has been splattered.

I will give it a try and see in the next years if b13 was worth it.

Answer (score 1):

First it depends what kind of container you want to realize.

If you don't really want to pack/wrap the contained CEs you can use the CE 'Records' which enables an editor to show multiple records from different positions in one place.

In the default rendering those records are rendered each without further wrapping.

Of course you can change the default rendering. but that would be an extension (except you do it by typoscript or templates below of `fileadmin/`), at least the site extension.

drawback:

- no preview in page BE module
- you need 'another' place to store the contained CEs, otherwise the CEs. would be shown twice (you could use another page, or another column (which does not get rendered)

You can vary the layout by evaluating the `layout` field of the records CE.

---

another solution with core oly:
add further 'layouts' so all ' contained' CEs get a special wrap which can be gathered with javascript into a container DOM object.